# Where can I contact Google to tell them my review isn't showing up?

Tags: google-maps

Where can I contact Google to tell them my review isn't showing up?

I wrote a review for a company I visited, but the review isn't showing up.

It shows on my end but not when i'm logged into another account or in an incognito window, so it only shows for me!

It has been more than a few weeks. Two months even.

Is there any way I can contact Google to chase it up?

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. Please consider to update the question.

Comment: @Rubén With What?!

Comment: You might improve the question wording based on what you have learned about Google Maps, or whatever to improve it's quality. It's up to you. Remember that this case mentioned because the question was bumped by Community User.

Comment: @Rubén okay.. question and answer seems good to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things you can try

**It looks like the best option I can see, is this- "option 1"**

https://www.localguidesconnect.com/t5/General-Discussion/UPDATED-Known-issue-RESOLVED-Unpublished-reviews-and-photos-on/m-p/2974938#M1143504

or

https://www.localguidesconnect.com/t5/General-Discussion/All-of-my-posts-and-reviews-cannot-be-showed-on-the-google-map/td-p/3463800

which mentions a form you can fill out to request for Google to have a look at it.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdEYYLY9EUPoAy9Wj_qqsbUd8kF9g_hiR0P2GXdrSoubu57og/viewform

---

**Another option or other options,  (not as good as the first option)**

I spoke to a person at google workspace chat and they said the don't deal with it directly, but there is a department that does, and they sent me to this link

https://support.google.com/business/gethelp

You could try an existing thread eg https://support.google.com/business/thread/171920366?hl=en

And I found when doing that I had to subscribe to the thread in order to reply to it. (otherwise it says "not signed in", when I am). (And even then couldn't post a link or an image e.g. link to the review or image of the review). So to post it I had to delete any link or image. Though it might be that a link or image isn't necessary 'cos maybe the person looking at your post can see everything anyway.

It Might be that starting a new thread is better.

You can start a new thread https://support.google.com/business/thread/new?source=need_more_help

commenter ruben mentions that that's for business owners.. and mentions  https://maps.google.com/localguides/

Though some threads there say nothing can be done, and others mention the link at option 1, that has the form you can fill out.

Comment: Google Business is pointed to Business owners. As a reviewer I think that you will have more chances to contact someone from Google if you go to the Google Maps community, more specifically to https://maps.google.com/localguides/

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to the question, it was bumped by Community User. Besides updating the question, please consider updating the answer. Have you tried the above links? What experience do you have with them?

Comment: @Rubén The review showed up eventually, so Google must have listened to one of my reports eventually! I tried every single link/method that I mentioned.

Comment: I'm glad that you got your issue solved. Thanks for confirming.